# Kohana 3.2 ORM and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, kohana, kohana-orm

I am giving Kohana a try and I was trying to use the ORM + PDO + MySQL database, and I don't seem to find an answer in google or SO.

I have both the database and ORM modules enabled, and I have set PDO as default in modules/database/config/database.php

I have a simple controller, and a simple model:

MODEL application/classes/model/blogpost.php:

```
<?php
class Model_Blogpost extends ORM {
    protected $_table_name  = 'blog_post'; 
}
```

CONTROLLER: in application/classes/controller/welcome.php

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Welcome extends Controller {

  public function action_index() {

    $Blog_Post = ORM::factory('blogpost');    // ==> ERROR HERE

    $Blog_Post->name = 'test1';
    $Blog_Post->description = 'this is a quick test';
    $Blog_Post->content = 'The content goes here....';
    $Blog_Post->save();

    $id = $Blog_Post->id;

    $Blog_Post = ORM::factory('blogpost', $id);
    $view->Blog_Post = $Blog_Post;

    $this->response->body($view);
  }
} // End Welcome
```

I get the following error when I try to run the test:

Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Database method list_columns is not supported by Kohana_Database_PDO

I have done a search in google and Stack Overflow, and my impression is that ORM may not work with PDO, is this correct? or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`list_columns` is used for ORM to get all the columns in a table when they are not specified. To get around this, you can specify the table columns in the `_table_columns` protected property:

```
class Model_Blogpost extends ORM {
  protected $_table_name  = 'blog_post';
  protected $_table_columns = array(
    'column1' => NULL,
    'column2' => NULL,
    // ...
    'columnx' => NULL,
  ); 
}
```

This will ensure that `list_columns` is not called. The downside is that you will have to keep track of every change to the table you make. The upside is that an extra `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` query is not called, meaning a small performance boost.

Another way is to override the `list_columns` method and provide your own means of listing columns with it.

Comment: Could you clarify the significance of the NULL values in the array? Does something need to be defined there, or will Kohana just be expecting NULL?

Comment: Nope, it does nothing. It reads the keys of the array, so you can put anything you want in the value. I use NULL

Comment: I wish I could vote this up more than once, because you just saved me a TON of grief! Very helpful! If only the Kahona docs could reach this level of detail...

Answer (score 3):

[here](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Kohana_Database_PDO#list_columns). Sometimes Kohana's docs can be confusing - never fear! the source code, while it might sound scary, is FULL with comments and actually serves as a really good docs.

Comment: You are right, that is confusing, so... there is no way around this? or the answer is 'no, you can't use pdo + ORM in kohana'?

Answer (score 2):

I just snagged the latest Kohana 3.3, and here's a link to help see why PDO isn't natively supported with ORM: http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/3412
Namely,

> There is no agnostic way to implement listing tables and columns.

So, uh I took a moment to try to support it since describing every table sounded like a lot of work, though that answer is appreciated!

So, in your MODPATH or APPPATH (depending on where you load your database stuff) make a new file at %above%/classes/Database/PDO/MySQL.php

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Database_PDO_MySQL extends Database_PDO {
    public function list_columns($table, $like = NULL, $add_prefix = TRUE)
    {
            // Quote the table name
            $table = ($add_prefix === TRUE) ? $this->quote_table($table) : $table;

            if (is_string($like))
            {
                    // Search for column names
                    $result = $this->query(Database::SELECT, 'SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM '.$table.' LIKE '.$this->quote($like), FALSE);
            }
            else
            {
                    // Find all column names
                    $result = $this->query(Database::SELECT, 'SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM '.$table, FALSE);
            }

            $count = 0;
            $columns = array();
            foreach ($result as $row)
            {
                    list($type, $length) = $this->_parse_type($row['Type']);

                    $column = $this->datatype($type);

                    $column['column_name']      = $row['Field'];
                    $column['column_default']   = $row['Default'];
                    $column['data_type']        = $type;
                    $column['is_nullable']      = ($row['Null'] == 'YES');
                    $column['ordinal_position'] = ++$count;

                    switch ($type) //was $column['type']
                    {
                            case 'float':
                                    if (isset($length))
                                    {
                                            list($column['numeric_precision'], $column['numeric_scale']) = explode(',', $length);
                                    }
                            break;
                            case 'int':
                                    if (isset($length))
                                    {
                                            // MySQL attribute
                                            $column['display'] = $length;
                                    }
                            break;
                           case 'string':
                                    switch ($column['data_type'])
                                    {
                                            case 'binary':
                                            case 'varbinary':
                                                    $column['character_maximum_length'] = $length;
                                            break;
                                            case 'char':
                                            case 'varchar':
                                                    $column['character_maximum_length'] = $length;
                                            case 'text':
                                            case 'tinytext':
                                            case 'mediumtext':
                                            case 'longtext':
                                                    $column['collation_name'] = $row['Collation'];
                                            break;
                                            case 'enum':
                                            case 'set':
                                                    $column['collation_name'] = $row['Collation'];
                                                    $column['options'] = explode('\',\'', substr($length, 1, -1));
                                            break;
                                    }
                            break;
                    }

                    // MySQL attributes
                    $column['comment']      = $row['Comment'];
                    $column['extra']        = $row['Extra'];
                    $column['key']          = $row['Key'];
                    $column['privileges']   = $row['Privileges'];

                    $columns[$row['Field']] = $column;
            }

            return $columns;
    }
}
```

What this is really, is me copying the %MODPATH%/database/classes/Kohana/databases/MySQL.php list_column and doing one tweak ($type instead of $column['type']) and it appears to work the little bit I've tested so far.

SECOND, you need to use the new driver. This is done by changing your %path%/database/config/database.php 'type' field from PDO to PDO_MySQL.

Let me know if this isn't clear, or if you see issues.

Comment: As of 3.3.2, ORM appears to be natively supported, making my above comment less useful.